# Android NFC, do a null check in onCreate?

Tags: android, tags, nullpointerexception, nfc, rfid

I have code to initialize my NFC adapter, but I am not sure how to intialize the variables during the onCreate. The app can be initialized whether an NFC TAG is in proximity or not, ie. if someone simply opened the app.    So when I get down to this line `NfcV nfcMessage = NfcV.get(new TagGet().getTag());` it crashes because it is null, there is no tag there if you just load the app on your own. How do I check here for `!= null` I'm not sure which part to check or how to structure this code.

The result is that I want to read the contents of the tag IFF a tag is present. Otherwise just load the layout and wait for a NfcV tag to be scanned.

```
// Setup an intent filter for all MIME based dispatches
    IntentFilter nfcv = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        nfcv.addDataType("*/*");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[] {
            nfcv,
    };

    // Setup a tech list for all NfcF tags
    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcV.class.getName() } };

    //mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);

    NfcV nfcMessage = NfcV.get(new TagGet().getTag());

    byte[] data = new byte[2048]; //tag length can't be any larger
    String value = "";
    try {
        data = nfcMessage.transceive(new byte[2048]);
        value = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: did you make the method "public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)" in the surrounding class? This way when your app is running and a tag is discovered onNewIntent runs. Then you can get your tag knowing that a tag is out there. Then you need to start another thread to handle the communication between your app and tag. You are headed in the right direction though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hear is a code outline of the basic way I made my first Nfc app. I tried to replace values (I used nfcA instead of nfcV) so you could read it better. It is a very basic structure, and you would need to fill in parts with your own code, but It should give you a good idea of how the structure of an NFC app can work.

```
public class Android_nfc_ibox extends Activity implements Runnable {




NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
private String[][] mTechLists;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
Tag tag;
NfcA mTag;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize the NFC adapter
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        dialog_text.append("Tap an NFC tag for access\n\r");
    } else {
        dialog_text.append("This phone is not NFC enabled\n\r");
    }

    // Create the PendingIntent object which will contain the details of the tag that has been scanned
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    // Setup a tech list for all desired tag types
    mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcA.class.getName() } };

}

    /** Re-enable the tag dispatch if the app is in the foreground */
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mNfcAdapter != null) mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, mTechLists);
    }

   /** Disable the tag dispatch when the app is no longer in the foreground */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mNfcAdapter != null) mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    /** A tag has been discovered */
    @Override 
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){

        // get the tag object for the discovered tag
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        // try and get the MifareUltralight instance for this tag
        mTag = NfcV.get(tag);

        // if null then this wasn't a NfcV tag so wait for next time
        if(mTag == null){
            dialog_text.append("Not a Nfc V tag\n\r");
        }

           // Start the tag communications thread
           Thread myThread = new Thread(this);
           myThread.start();

        }
    }

   // (we could create other threads for other types of tags)
   public void run(){
       // try to connect to the Nfc V tag
       try{

           mTag.connect();
       }catch(IOException e){
            //handle the error here
       }

       //this will send raw data
       //send the values you want in the byte[]
       //just add the raw hex values with commas
       //pageBuffer is an array that will hold the response
       try{
           pageBuffer = mTag.transceive(new byte[] {0x11, 0x24, 0x11});
       }catch(IOException e){
            //handle error here
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks ben, this is very helpful! `mTag.transceive(new byte[] {0x11, 0x24, 0x11});`  this does not work for me to send to my NfcV tag to read from (I guess its the wrong hex) why are you using those hex values and how did you determine to use those, how could I find the proper "read" command for my NfcV devices?

Comment: Sorry, it was mainly random nonsense, I just wanted to show where the hex commands would go. I believe that the command you would want would be 0x20 followed by the block number, so (0x20, 0x06) to read block 6. But, from a short Google search it might be (0x00, 0x20, 0x06)

Comment: A write would be 0x21. Each block appears to have 4 bytes, and the code to write one block looks to be (0x40, 0x21, 0x06, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04) The first byte is for flags, the second is the command (read or write) the third is the block number and the next 4 are the data you are writing.

Comment: wait! what is your search string! "iso 16539 write command" is getting me nowhere!

Comment: I am able to retrieve partial data here (I am only reading). using `{0x00, 0x20, 0x01}` and I do get 4 bytes in return, but if I add more bytes after that it crashes. if I change the third one, then I can read things from that respective block, but not from all the blocks! Maybe just need a while loop, but if I could just list them all in the array here that'd be perfect.

Comment: I searched "ISO 15693" and the third hit was a document from TI called "ISO 15639 Host Commands" I believe it references their own nfc chip and evaluation board. They listed another command, "Read multiple Blocks." it's format is (0x00, 0x23, 0x01, 0x02) again first byte is for flags, second is the command, the third is the start byte and the fourth is the number of blocks to read.

Comment: SUCCESS! Thank you Ben. I had to do for loop with a string array, trim and concatenate, but this all put me in the right direction!

Comment: Don't worry about it, I made a function to handle this glitch.